# Python web scraping: websites from google search result

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, web-crawler, google-crawlers

A newbie to Python here. I want to extract info from multiple websites (e.g. 100+) from a google search page. I just want to extract the key info, e.g. those with `<h1>`, `<h2>` or `<b>` or `<li>` HTML tags etc. But I don't want to extract the entire paragraph `<p>`.

I know how to gather a list of website URLs from that google search; and I know how to web scrape individual website after looking at the page's HTML. I use the Request and BeautifulSoup for these tasks.

However, I want to know how can I extract key info from all these (100+ !) websites without having to look at their html one by one. Is there a way to automatically find out the HTML tags the website used to emphasize key messages? e.g. some websites may use `<h1>`, while some may use `<b>` , or something else...

All I can think of is to come up with a list of possible "emphasis-typed" HTML tags and then just use BeautifulSoup.find_all() to do a wide-scale extraction. But surely there must be an easier way?

Comment: From what I understand you are wanting to open each link, first I suggest using inspect elements and find out what tag those links are under.

If i google `how to share a song on instagram story from spotify` the link I'm looking at is called All the Ways to Share Your Songs on Socials From Spotify ...

It has a tag of `<a href>` to get all links I would do something like this.

`soup = BeautifulSoup(open(DATA_PATH + "SERACH", encoding='utf-8'), "html.parser")`

start a for loop that looks for links

```
for link in soup.select(THAT TAG):
    link_name = name.get("href")
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment; yes, I know how to use inspect element; trouble is I don't want to do this inspecting part for each of the website from my google search result list. So, my question is there an automatic way to do this step, i.e. find out the html tags used as emphasis for different websites?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you must first learn how to do loops and function first. Every website is completely different and scraping a website alone to extract useful information is daunting. I'm a newb myself, but if I have to extract info from headers like you, this is what I would do: (this is just concept code, but hope you'll find it useful)

```
def getLinks(articleUrl):
 html = urlopen('http://en.web.com{}'.format(articleUrl))
 bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
 return bs.find('h1', {'class':'header'}).find_all('h1',
 header=re.compile('^(/web/)((?!:).)*$'))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know how to scrape each ***individual*** website and to use for loop to dig info from a list of website. Issue here is I don't know what tag to use for each different website. So, e.g. website #1 may use 'h1' tag to mark important content; while website #2 use 'b' tag, website #3 use 'i' tag etc.



I can inspect element of website one by one and see which tag they use for important info in their site; but is there an automatic way to do this step?